# bundle install doesn't work on with RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, git, bundle-install

I have a problem installing my bundle.

These were my last steps:

- `git clone http:...`
- `git checkout -b daniel`
- `bundle install`

The error I got was:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
extension.

        /Users/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby extconf.rb  checking for main() in -lpthread... yes checking for main() in
-lobjc... yes
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
options.

Provided configuration options:     --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
    --with-pthreadlib   --without-pthreadlib    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib   --enable-debug  --disable-debug
/Users/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/build.rb:50:in
`build_with_rubygem_libv8': undefined local variable or method
`libv8_include_flags' for main:Object (NameError)   from
extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0 for
inspection. Results logged to
/Users/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.0), and Bundler
cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

When I tried to run `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'` I got:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
installing therubyracer:    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for main() in -lpthread... yes checking for main() in
-lobjc... yes
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
options.

Provided configuration options:     --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
    --with-pthreadlib   --without-pthreadlib    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib   --enable-debug  --disable-debug
/Users/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/build.rb:50:in
`build_with_rubygem_libv8': undefined local variable or method
`libv8_include_flags' for main:Object (NameError)   from
extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0 for
inspection. Results logged to
/Users/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

I am working on Mac OS 10.7.5. Xcode and its command line tools and Rails are up to date.
SQLite 3 is also installed.

Can anyone help me?

---

EDIT:

I also tried to delete the repository and to clone it again, with the same errors.

---

EDIT:

Is the installation path of Rails and Sqlite3 correct?

```
daniel:~ 
daniel$ sudo gem update --system Latest version currently
installed. Aborting. 
daniel:~ 
daniel$ sudo gem install rails 
Fetching:
rails-3.2.11.gem (100%) Successfully installed 
rails-3.2.11 1 gem installed 
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.11... 
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.11... 
daniel:~ 
daniel$ sudo gem install sqlite3
Fetching: sqlite3-1.3.7.gem (100%) 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... 
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.7 1 gem installed 
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.7... 
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-1.3.7...
daniel:~ 
daniel$ which ruby irb gem rake
/Users/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
/Users/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/irb
/Users/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/gem
/Users/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/rake
```

Comment: Have you accepted the XCode license agreement?

Comment: I can start XCode and create new project etc. So i thing i have accepted it. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: What version of libv8 are you using?

Comment: I noticed, that i dont' use libv8:

Comment: daniel:~ daniel$ bundle show libv8
Could not locate Gemfile
daniel:~ daniel$ gem install libv8
Successfully installed libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-darwin-11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-darwin-11...
Installing RDoc documentation for libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-darwin-11...

Comment: After installing libv8 i started bundle install in my project-folder. But the same error exists again ...

Comment: Installing therubyracer (0.11.0) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Upgrading to therubyracer (0.11.2) will likely fix things.

Comment: Please take the time to learn how to format your question. As is, it's very difficult to read, which slows anyone trying to help you, and will drive off a lot of potential help.

Comment: "gem uninstall libv8" and "gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.2'" doesn't work. When i try to run "bundle install" - the same error is displayed. @the Tin Man: Sorry. New languages (english and ruby) etc. I try to take the time to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

At least one problem is that you are running RVM, but used `sudo` to install gems on your system.

Read "[RVM and RubyGems](https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems/)", especially the part that says:

## "DO NOT use sudo..."

RVM creates a sandbox for you, the user, in your own user-space on a machine, that allows you to manage it without needing to be the system administrator. In other words, that means you don't have to use `sudo` for any RVM or gems management.

If you do use `sudo`, you temporarily cease being you, the user, and become the administrator, with administrator privileges and the administrator's environment, which does *NOT* include the RVM sandbox in your `/Users/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286` path. Knowledge of the sandbox is carried by the PATH in your environment, which the root on your machine doesn't use. Gems installed inside that `sudo` sub-shell get installed into the location that the administrator account knows about, which is inside the System Ruby installation, which is why your RVM sandboxed Ruby doesn't see them: There is no crossover between the System's Ruby and your RVM-controlled RUby. That's the whole idea of a sandbox: separation of the elements and resources to avoid contamination.

You could have figured this all out by looking at the output of:

```
which ruby irb gem rake
```

The path for all of them is pointing to your sandbox:

```
/Users/daniel/.rvm/rubies
```

On a Mac OS system, that command should have reported:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/irb
/usr/bin/gem
/usr/bin/rake
```

Reinstall Rails and the SQLite gem using:

```
gem install rails sqlite3
```

and see how your bundle behaves.

And, by the way, do NOT use `sudo` to deliberately try to manage/delete the System installed Ruby. That was installed by Apple for their own purposes, to enable software they installed. It's OK to take advantage of its existence, but it's there for their use. Use a RVM-managed Ruby for your own purposes.

Comment: Thank u for all your answers! I fixed the problem on my own. After installing therubyracer Version 0.10.2 the command "bundle install" runs fine. Thanks again guys!

Comment: Same problem here. I had to change version of libv8 to 3.3.10 and therubyracer to 0.10.2.